# touch issue with Raphael path

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, raphael

I have issue with freeline (Raphael)path when using touch. When i draw something with free hand, sometimes a straight line protrudes just before the fee line stops and connects to the center point of the raphael paper. Anyone have faced this issue? I attached a screen shot of what i am facing, i have marked in red the unwanted lines that connect to the center of the raphael paper.

Update: Created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackit/h4Wrr/)

Update2: Noticed that this issue happen in the android browser when drawing takes little long. Even if i just touch on the canvas for few sec, the touch point connect to the center by creating a line and the screen blinks when that happens. So, i am thinking it is something related to touch event when it touched for few seconds.

[image]

```
var board = $("#board");
board.bind("mousedown", _mousedownHandler);
        board.bind("touchstart", _mousedownHandler);
function _drawFreeLineBegin(x, y) {
        board.lineEl.path = _drawOptions.paper.path("M"
                + (x - _drawOptions.offset.left) + ","
                + (y - _drawOptions.offset.top));
        _setNewElementProperties(board.lineEl.path,
                Configuration.getProperties("freeLine"));
            board.bind("mousemove.mmu", _mousemoveHandler);
        board.one("mouseup.mmu", _mouseupHandler);
        board.bind("touchmove.mmu", _mousemoveHandler);
        board.one("touchend.mmu", _mouseupHandler);
    }
function _mousedownHandler(event) {
if(event.type == "touchstart"){
            event = event.originalEvent.touches\[0\];
        }
_drawFreeLineBegin(event.pageX, event.pageY);
return false;
}

    function _mousemoveHandler(event) {
    if(event.type == "touchmove"){
            event = event.originalEvent.touches\[0\];
        }
    board.lineEl.path
                        .attr(
                                "path",
                                board.lineEl.path.attr("path")
                                        + "L"
                                        + (event.pageX - )
                                        + ","
                                        + (event.pageY ));
                return true;

}

function _mouseupHandler(event) {
board.unbind(".mmu");
 board.lineEl.path = null;
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
}
```